How do i change the HorizontalBarChart's gridlines and axis color to another color? And how do i show text on the bars for MPAndroidChart in Kotlin?
I'm working with a HorizontalBarChart in MPAndroidChart and need to customize the appearance of the labels, text and grid lines. Here's what I've tried so far:
Removing and Adding bar labels: I've tried using setDrawValueLabelsEnabled(true) on the BarDataset object but it is not recognised.
Adjusting grid lines: I've tried setDrawGridLines(false) to remove grid lines, but I want to remove them behind the data as well.
Here's my xml code:
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.HorizontalBarChart
                android:id="@+id/extraversionchart"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/extraversionlayoutdiv" />

And here's my kotlin code:
extrachart = findViewById(R.id.extraversionchart)
val dataEntriesExtroversion = mutableListOf<BarEntry>()
val labelsExtroversion = mutableListOf<String>()
var personalityResultsExtroversion = mutableMapOf<String, Int>()
        personalityoutputmap.get("EXTRAVERSION")?.let { personalityResultsExtroversion.put("EXTRAVERSION", it) }
        personalityoutputmap.get("Friendliness")?.let { personalityResultsExtroversion.put("Friendliness", it) }
        personalityoutputmap.get("Gregariousness")?.let { personalityResultsExtroversion.put("Gregariousness", it) }
        personalityoutputmap.get("Assertiveness")?.let { personalityResultsExtroversion.put("Assertiveness", it) }
        personalityoutputmap.get("Activity Level")?.let { personalityResultsExtroversion.put("Activity Level", it) }
        personalityoutputmap.get("Excitement-Seeking")?.let { personalityResultsExtroversion.put("Excitement-Seeking", it) }
        personalityoutputmap.get("Cheerfulness")?.let { personalityResultsExtroversion.put("Cheerfulness", it) }
for ((label, value) in personalityResultsExtroversion) {
            dataEntriesExtroversion.add(BarEntry(dataEntriesExtroversion.size.toFloat(), value.toFloat()))
            labelsExtroversion.add(label)
        }
dataEntriesExtroversion.reverse()
labelsExtroversion.reverse()
val barDataSetExtroversion = BarDataSet(dataEntriesExtroversion, "Extraversion Traits")
barDataSetExtroversion.setValueTextColor(color)
barDataSetExtroversion.setColors(color)
val barDataExtroversion = BarData(barDataSetExtroversion)
extrachart.data = barDataExtroversion
extrachart.invalidate()

How can I achieve the following:
Add labels for each bar.
Remove the grid lines behind the data.
Change color of lines/values in the chart to a specific color (Because in night mode, no lines or values or text are visible)
Here's how it is looking currently in my app: Chart in night and light mode
